# Ionic Local Notification Sound not working on Android 8.0

Tags: android, ionic-framework, ionic3, localnotification

Provide a general summary of the issue.

### Environment

- Plugin version: 0.9.0-beta.2
- Platform: Android
- OS version: 8.0.x
- Device manufacturer / model: Samsung Galaxy s8
- Cordova version (`cordova -v`): 4.2.1
- Cordova platform version (`cordova platform ls`): 7.1.4
- Plugin config: none
- Ionic Version: 3.9.2

### Expected Behavior

Using:

```
this.localNotifications.schedule({
                    id: 1,
                    text: 'You have arrived',
                    sound: 'file://assets/sounds/alerts/arrival.mp3',
                    data: { secret: 'hellloo' },
                    vibrate: true
                });
```

I want to display a notification with a custom sound
Located in `src/assets/sounds/alerts/...`

### Actual Behavior

I've tried every possible filepath (I think) however it still plays the default Samsung Galaxy s8 notification sound.

### Debug logs

Logcat output:

```
02-28 17:38:06.354  3779  3779 D EdgeLightingManager: showForNotification : isInteractive=true, isHeadUp=false, color=0, sbn = StatusBarNotification(pkg=io.ionic.starter user=UserHandle{0} id=1 tag=null key=0|io.ionic.starter|1|null|10203: Notification(channel=default-channel-id pri=0 contentView=null vibrate=null sound=null tick defaults=0x0 flags=0x11 color=0x00000000 number=0 vis=PUBLIC semFlags=0x0 semPriority=0 semMissedCount=0))
02-28 17:38:06.354  3779  3779 D EdgeLightingPolicyManager: putNotification tickerText:true,titleText:true,text:true,sub:falsecn= + null
02-28 17:38:06.354  3779  3779 D EdgeLightingPolicyManager.NotificationGroup: updateNotificationData put :0|io.ionic.starter|1|null|10203,size=7
02-28 17:38:06.354  3779  3779 D EdgeLightingPolicyManager.NotificationGroup: 0|io.ionic.starter|1|null|10203:NotificationData time=1551371886354,
02-28 17:38:06.354  3779  3779 D EdgeLightingPolicyManager.NotificationGroup: 0|android|40|null|1000:NotificationData time=1551371251595,
02-28 17:38:06.355  3779  3779 D EdgeLightingPolicyManager.NotificationGroup: 0|com.rolflex.mobCSRApp|6|null|10156:NotificationData time=1551291051811,
02-28 17:38:06.355  3779  3779 D EdgeLightingPolicyManager.NotificationGroup: 0|com.wssyncmldm|1|null|1000:NotificationData time=1551349895823,
02-28 17:38:06.355  3779  3779 D EdgeLightingPolicyManager.NotificationGroup: 0|com.google.android.apps.maps|g:atn_group:NotificationData time=1551371775363,
02-28 17:38:06.355  3779  3779 D EdgeLightingPolicyManager.NotificationGroup: 0|com.rolflex.mobCSRApp|-574543954|null|10156:NotificationData time=1551291051833,
02-28 17:38:06.355  3779  3779 D EdgeLightingPolicyManager.NotificationGroup: 0|com.android.vending|874755343|null|10043:NotificationData time=1551314492705,
02-28 17:38:06.355  3779  3779 D EdgeLightingPolicyManager.NotificationGroup: 0|com.android.settings|9|null|1000:NotificationData time=1550852356484,
02-28 17:38:06.355  3779  3779 D EdgeLightingManager: showForNotificationScreenOn : return false by isAcceptableApplication.
02-28 17:38:06.365  3779  3779 I AccessibilityManagerService: semOnLightNotification(null), bIsFlashOn : false
02-28 17:38:06.372  4196  4196 D StatusBar: addNotification key=0|io.ionic.starter|1|null|10203 fullscreen:false
02-28 17:38:06.460  3426 15233 V NuPlayer: onSourceNotify() kWhatFlagsChanged  FLAG_CAN_PAUSE: 1  FLAG_CAN_SEEK_BACKWARD: 1 
02-28 17:38:06.461  3426 15233 V NuPlayer: NuPlayer::onSourceNotify Source::kWhatPrepared source: 0xe7d6dc40
```

I've noticed that 'sound = null' is being logged, which is kind of weird.
Thanks in advance.

With kind regards,

Jonah